# Mocking dynamodb scan using jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, aws-sdk, bluebird

For the source code(dynamodb.js)：

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk"); 
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
module.exports.db = (method, params) => {
  console.log("access dynamodb ");
  return Promise.fromCallback(cb => client[method](params, cb));
};
```

Using the test that looks like this(dont want't to mock Promise.fromCallback):

```
describe("test", () => {
  const realAWS = require("aws-sdk");
  let fakePromise;
  let fakeDynamo;
  let dbClient;
  beforeAll(function() {
    fakePromise = jest.fn();
    fakeDynamo = {
      get: (params, cb) => {
        fakePromise(params, cb);
      }
    };
    realAWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient = jest.fn(() => fakeDynamo);
    dbClient = require("../dynamodb");
  });
  test.only("Test successed", done => {
    let result = dbClient.db("get", null);
    console.log("access dynamodb ");
    expect(fakePromise).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

but when tun the test ,the error was heppend:

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

if anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the implementation of the `client.get` method as a node callback style. So that `Promise.fromCallback` method will covert callback style to a promise.

Besides, you need to trigger the callback in your test case. That's why you got a timeout error.

E.g.

`dynamodb.js`:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.db = (method, params) => {
  console.log('access dynamodb');
  return Promise.fromCallback((cb) => client[method](params, cb));
};
```

`dynamodb.test.js`:

```js
const { db } = require('./dynamodb');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  const mClient = { get: jest.fn() };
  const mDynamoDB = {
    DocumentClient: jest.fn(() => mClient),
  };
  return { DynamoDB: mDynamoDB };
});

const mockClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

describe('54360588', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    mockClient.get.mockImplementationOnce((err, callback) => {
      callback(null, 'fake data');
    });
    const actual = await db('get', null);
    expect(actual).toBe('fake data');
    expect(mockClient.get).toBeCalledWith(null, expect.any(Function));
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/54360588/dynamodb.test.js (10.74s)
  54360588
    ✓ should pass (28ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/54360588/dynamodb.js:177
    access dynamodb

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 dynamodb.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.636s
```